# VHDL 3-bit u/d counter

Tags: vhdl, counter

i have this vhdl code for a  3-bit up/down counter , but when i simulate it do not give any output result, what is wrong??

```
   library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity counter is
  Port ( rst,clk : in STD_LOGIC;
   up: in bit;
          z : out STD_LOGIC_vector( 2 downto 0 ));
end counter;
architecture Behavioral of Counter is
signal zint:  STD_LOGIC_vector( 2 downto 0 ) ; 
begin
z<= zint;
 process (clk)
begin
if (clk' event and clk='1') then 
if (rst ='1') then 
zint <= "000" ;
end if;
if (zint <= "111" )then zint <= "000";
elsif (up='1') then zint <= zint+1;
else zint <= zint-1;
end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Usually it is better to give an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that someone else can reproduce your fault, but in this case I think I can see what is wrong.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Please show your testbench. What do you mean by _do not give any output result_?

Answer (score 0):

You set `zint` to "000" on reset. Then, as long as `zint` is less equal "111" you set it to "000" again. How can `zint` become different from "000"?
You could drop the first if condition completely, the counter will automatically overflow from "111" to "000" or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem:

```
if (zint <= "111" )then zint <= "000";
```

didn't you mean this?

```
if (zint = "111" )then zint <= "000";
```

In fact, you don't need the above line at all - the counter will automatically wrap-round. (And, the same is true for counting down, a situation you have no code for, anyway.)

Having said that, here are some other suggestions to improve your code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;        -- DON'T USE THIS...
use ieee.numeric_std.all;                  -- ...USE THIS INSTEAD
entity counter is
  Port ( rst,clk : in STD_LOGIC;
   up: in bit;                             -- DID YOU REALLY WANT TYPE 'bit' HERE?
   z : out STD_LOGIC_vector( 2 downto 0 ));
end counter;

architecture Behavioral of Counter is
  signal zint:  unsigned( 2 downto 0 ) ;   -- MAKE THIS TYPE 'unsigned'...
begin
  z<= std_logic_vector(zint);              -- ... AND USE A TYPE CONVERSION HERE
  process (clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then               -- '(clk' event and clk='1')' BECAME OLD-FASHIONED in 1993!
      if rst ='1' then                     -- YOU DON'T NEED THE BRACKETS
        zint <= "000" ;                    -- USE INDENTATION!
      --end if;
      --if zint = "111" then zint <= "000";
      elsif up='1' then
        zint <= zint+1;
      else
        zint <= zint-1;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```